# How to send initial data with sse (using express-sse library)?

Tags: node.js, express, server-sent-events

Im using a sse express library ('express-sse'). I am doing everything like in the documentation but I cant get an initial value. On my client I am getting events though. Im stuck on this for long and would appreciate any help. I also added the actual code from the library but cannot figure out whats causing the initial value not to be send.

```
const SSE = require("express-sse");
const sse = new SSE(["test"], { isSerialized: true, initialEvent: 'firstTest' });
//also tried: 
const sse = new SSE(["test"]);
const sse = new SSE();
module.exports = sse;
```

route handler:

```
app.use(router.get('/notifications_stream',  sse.init))
```

client:

```
 const eventSource = new EventSource(url, {
         headers: {
             Authorization: {
                 toString: function () {
                      return "Bearer " + token;
                 },
             },
         },
 });

 eventSource.addEventListener('open', (e) => {
      console.log("connection is open", e)
 });//open event is called after connection is established as the only event
 eventSource.onmessage = function (event) {} //nothing happens here
 eventSource.addEventListener("firstTest", function (event) {}) //nothing happens here
 eventSource.addEventListener("message", function (event) {}) //nothing happens here, even though this is suppose to run whenever no event is defined

 eventSource.addEventListener(`new_notification-${userUd}`, function (event) {}) //works later
```

Later when I send data and define an event like this:

```
await sse.send(someData, `new_notification-${userUd}`);
```

it does work. I also tried to immidiatly after initializing it, using sse.send but nothing happens here.

code from library:

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Require the module dependencies
 */

const EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;

/**
 * Server-Sent Event instance class
 * @extends EventEmitter
 */
class SSE extends EventEmitter {
  /**
   * Creates a new Server-Sent Event instance
   * @param [array] initial Initial value(s) to be served through SSE
   * @param [object] options SSE options
   */
  constructor(initial, options) {
    super();

    if (initial) {
      this.initial = Array.isArray(initial) ? initial : [initial];
    } else {
      this.initial = [];
    }

    if (options) {
      this.options = options;
    } else {
      this.options = { isSerialized: true };
    }

    this.init = this.init.bind(this);
  }

  /**
   * The SSE route handler
   */
  init(req, res) {
    let id = 0;
    req.socket.setTimeout(0);
    req.socket.setNoDelay(true);
    req.socket.setKeepAlive(true);
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/event-stream');
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('X-Accel-Buffering', 'no');
    if (req.httpVersion !== '2.0') {
      res.setHeader('Connection', 'keep-alive');
    }
    if (this.options.isCompressed) {
      res.setHeader('Content-Encoding', 'deflate');
    }

    // Increase number of event listeners on init
    this.setMaxListeners(this.getMaxListeners() + 2);

    const dataListener = data => {
      if (data.id) {
        res.write(`id: ${data.id}\n`);
      } else {
        res.write(`id: ${id}\n`);
        id += 1;
      }
      if (data.event) {
        res.write(`event: ${data.event}\n`);
      }
      res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data.data)}\n\n`);
      res.flush();
    };

    const serializeListener = data => {
      const serializeSend = data.reduce((all, msg) => {
        all += `id: ${id}\ndata: ${JSON.stringify(msg)}\n\n`;
        id += 1;
        return all;
      }, '');
      res.write(serializeSend);
    };

    this.on('data', dataListener);

    this.on('serialize', serializeListener);

    if (this.initial) {
      if (this.options.isSerialized) {
        this.serialize(this.initial);
      } else if (this.initial.length > 0) {
        this.send(this.initial, this.options.initialEvent || false);
      }
    }

    // Remove listeners and reduce the number of max listeners on client disconnect
    req.on('close', () => {
      this.removeListener('data', dataListener);
      this.removeListener('serialize', serializeListener);
      this.setMaxListeners(this.getMaxListeners() - 2);
    });
  }

  /**
   * Update the data initially served by the SSE stream
   * @param {array} data array containing data to be served on new connections
   */
  updateInit(data) {
    this.initial = Array.isArray(data) ? data : [data];
  }

  /**
   * Empty the data initially served by the SSE stream
   */
  dropInit() {
    this.initial = [];
  }

  /**
   * Send data to the SSE
   * @param {(object|string)} data Data to send into the stream
   * @param [string] event Event name
   * @param [(string|number)] id Custom event ID
   */
  send(data, event, id) {
    this.emit('data', { data, event, id });
  }

  /**
   * Send serialized data to the SSE
   * @param {array} data Data to be serialized as a series of events
   */
  serialize(data) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      this.emit('serialize', data);
    } else {
      this.send(data);
    }
  }
}

module.exports = SSE;
```